# Как разумнее: "котъ и мышь" или "кот и мыш", "врачъ и помощь" или "врач и помощ", и т. д.?

Tags: орфография

Вопрос сформулирован в заголовке.

Примечание:

1. В выражении "котъ и мышь" знак "ъ" указывает на мужской род кота, а знак "ь" указывает на женский род мыши.
2. В выражении "кот и мыш" нет знаков, которые указывают на мужской род кота и женский род мыши.

Comment: Грамматический "ъ" и грамматический "ь" похожи на магнитные заряды "N" и "S". Иначе говоря, грамматические "ъ" и "ь" это такие же продукты воображения как, например, флогистон.

Answer (score 5):

Для мыши всего разумнее не высовываться из группы существительных женского рода 3-его склонения, которые все пишутся с мягким знаком: степь, тень, ветвь, гарь и т.д.

А то кот поймает.

Comment: Кто? - Пишу "мышь", но не слышу грамматического знака "ь".

Кого? - Пишу "мыши", но слышу "мышы". Куда-то пропал знак "ь".

Кому? - Пишу "мыши", но слышу "мышы". Куда-то пропал знак "ь" снова.

...

Кем? - Пишу "мышью", а слышу "мышйу". Уря! Знак "ь" объявился в качестве разделительного знака.


P.S. И почему только сокращается число физических лиц, говорящих на русском языке?

Comment: Грамматический знак не слышат и не слушают, он фонетику не обозначает. Грамматический Ь позволяет мыши не быть изгоем, чувствовать себя социально обозначенной и во всех падежах соответствовать своему склонению: мышь - мыши - мышью, тень - тени - тенью. Думаю, что физические лица будут вполне удовлетворены таким объяснением.

Comment: Милая София.

Я плакаль, когда читал как "грамматический Ь позволяет мыши не быть изгоем, чувствовать себя социально обозначенной и во всех падежах соответствовать своему склонению".

Answer (score 3):

Какой-то некорректный вопрос. Что значит "как разумнее"? Разумно писать, соблюдая орфографические правила и учитывая особенности некоторых звуков. Или это провокационный вопрос?)

Answer (score 3):

Галактион,  вы  постоянно  смешиваете  или  не  различаете  язык ( аудиосистему ) и  письменность  (  а  это  попытка  выразить  звуковые  аналоги  графическими  символами ).  Развитие  языка  идёт по законам  языка,  ещё  не  полностью  изученным,  но  по  законам  (  как  и  всё  в  природе ).  Орфография  управляется  правилами,  выработанными  практикой.  Вы  сами  знаете,  правила  меняются,  но  остаются  правилами,  которым  надо  следовать. Русскому  языку,  как  аудиосистеме,  не  так  уж  важно,  напишете  вы  мышь  или  мыш.  Да  и  читающий  тоже  разберётся,  о  чём  вы  сообщаете.  Но  вывод  о  вашей  грамотности,  наверное,  сделает. Но  ведь  бывают и  такие  ошибки,  что  не  всегда  разберёшь,  о  чём  человек  пишет.  А  нарушаются  всего  лишь  орфографические  правила.

Answer (score 0):

"Разумнее - не отвечать на такие вопросы.
Как правильнее - так и разумнее.
Другого критерия разумности нет."

отвечен 12 Июн '14 14:28
behemothus's gravatar image
behemothus